# Size of play newsstand gridview images?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gridview, image-resizing

I want to create a **gridview exactly like that in Google play newsstand (picture link below)**, i did research but i cannot find out what resolution to make the images for each dpi (ldpi, hdpi, etc.).

Does anyone have the answer for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Android-PlayStoreGridView](https://github.com/n00blet/Android-PlayStoreGridView/tree/master/GooglePlayLikeGrid) is near to similar with google play store like grid.

All image size are mentioned in resource folder.

[image]